# Master Detail Pattern w/LOCAL data

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new to the Angular JS coding structure and I have been successful at being able to pull data using an $hhtp.get method from a JSON, but now I am trying to practice with local data. I am trying to create a Master Details Pattern that shows a items details (price, specs, make, etc), but I'm trying to pass an array of products in one controller into the "Details" controller, but I am not successful. All of the routing works perfectly, it's just that the details page (product.html) does not show a specific item's details. I'm not sure how to go about it using a service.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Below is my code snippet.

Controllers.Js

```js
.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.products= [
 {
 title: 'iPhone 6',
 cover:'img/iphone6.png',
 description: 'Apple Device of the New Age',
    price:459.99,
    id: 1
 },
 {
     title: 'iPhone 6 Plus',
     cover: 'img/iPhone-6-Plus.png',
     description: 'Apple Device of New Age 2',
        price:499.99,
        id: 2
 },
    {
        title: 'iPad Air',
        cover: 'img/iPadAir.png',
        description: 'Apple iPad Air 2',
        price:299.99,
        id:3
    },
    {
        title: 'Dell Inspiron 15.6"',
        cover: 'img/dellLaptop.png',
        description: 'This is a laptop made by Dell',
        price:499.99,
        id:4
    },
    {
        title: 'Galaxy S6 Edge',
        cover: 'img/galaxy-s6-edge.png',
        description: 'Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge',
        price:399.99,
        id:5
    }
 ];

})

.controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, detailsService, Products) {
    
    $scope.detail = Products;
    
    
});
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Details" id="page5">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        <div class="list card"  ng-controller="detailsCtrl">

            <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img ng-src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BeQW1K0oGvM/UOqF8XFqKsI/AAAAAAAAH48/24ZEet_mKY8/s1600/google-chrome-black-centre.png">
                <h2>{{detail.title}}</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-image">
                <img ng-src="{{detail.cover}}">
            </div>
            <div class="item item-divider">
                Product Specs
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <ul>
                <li>&bull;4.7-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit widescreen Multi-Touch display with IPS technology</li>
                   <li>&bull;New 8-megapixel iSight camera with 1.5 pixels</li>
                    <li>&bull;A8 chip with 64-bit architecture. M8 motion coprocessor</li>
                   <li> &bull;1080p HD video recording (30 fps or 60 fps)</li>
                   <li>&bull;Unlocked cell phones are compatible with GSM carriers like H2O Wireless.</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="button button-icon-left button-assertive button-block" ng-click="addtoCart()">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-cart"></i>
                Add to Cart
            </button>

        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: make a plunker please. 
you cannot share datas between two controllers without a service that you will inject in both (like Products ). the first controller should write in Products and detailsCtrl read from it.

Comment: and in your first controller products in an array but in the view you don't use ng-repeat to display each product

Comment: @Alainlb Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dA2tNXay9wUE8JZgwqdH?p=info) for the project. Am I to store my array in a service or keep it inside the controller?

Comment: you need to share datas between controller / directive or services : keep it in a service

Comment: @Alainlb I got it! Thank you for your advice! I placed the array inside of a service and merely injected the service into both controllers like you advised! thank you!